# java how not to add the element if it starts with specific character

Tags: java

I got a txt file starting with different characters and imported them to arraylist. Now how can I stop the program from adding the word into the arraylist if it starts with #? I'm thinking something like

```
static ArrayList<String> fruitList= new ArrayList<String>();
public static void main(String[]args)
{
try {
    Scanner c = new Scanner(new File("D:/test/Fruits.txt"));
    while (c.hasNextLine())
    {
        fruitList.add(c.nextLine());
        if (c.startsWith("#"){
        // I dont know what to write here
        }
    }
    c.close();
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or:

```
while (c.hasNextLine()) {
     line = c.nextLine();
     if (!line.startsWith("#")) {
         fruitList.add(line);
     }
}
```

Comment: Does the Scanner class have a `startsWith()` method? If not it needs to be `!line.startsWith("#")`.

Comment: Yeah that's my bad, it produced an error in eclipse. So where should I put that line? Beginner here @Tarlen

Comment: Just instead of the `!c.startsWith("#")` inside the if-statement. So the whole if statement looks like this: `if(!line.startsWith("#")) {fruitList.add(line)}`. This way you check whether the line, which you read via the Scanner, starts with your "comment" character. I fixed this in the answer.

Comment: @Tarlen and MarounMaroun I see. The code worked beautifully. Thanks guys :)